# Transforming a system of PDE's: linear and nonlinear

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, heat-equation, linear-pde

Consider the following system of partial differential equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
2\sqrt{s}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s} \sqrt{\mp \Omega_s(x)}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\pm\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x)} \\
 s \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\Omega_s(x)=\pm x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x) 
\end{cases}
$$

for Cauchy data given by $$\Omega_s(x)|_{s=0}$$

I discovered this system in the following way: I leveraged the ansatz that $\Omega_s(x)$ was a Cauchy foliation of a Lorentzian manifold $M,$ isometric to the classical Minkowski $(1+1)$ space in Dirac coordinates.

Working under these assumptions I derived that we should have $(M,g)$ with $g=\frac{dudv}{uv}.$

Next, I embedded $\Omega_s(x)$ in a Riemannian manifold, $\Bbb R^2$ with Cartesian coordinates and the usual metric. Then I showed that $\Omega_s(x)=e^{\frac{\mp s}{\log x}}$ for $x\ne 0,1$ satisfies the above system of equations.

There is a way to generalize and look at the $(n \times n)$ space and time lattice, which then the above system of equations corresponds to the lattice point $(1,1).$ In fact for any point on the lattice $(1,n)$ these lattice points correspond to solutions to an $n$-dim. version of the linear equation in the above system whilst any point on the lattice $(n,1)$ these lattice points correspond to solutions to an $n$-dim. version the the nonlinear equation in the above system.

And the point $(1,1)$ is special in that it corresponds to a solution to both the nonlinear and linear equation simultaneously.

The generalization of:

$$2\sqrt{s}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s} \sqrt{\mp \Omega_s(x)}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\pm\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x)}$$

is

$$\frac{2\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{x_1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \sqrt{\mp g}=\Psi g$$

for

$$\Psi g := \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\pm \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g}$$

where

$$g:=\prod_{i=1}^n \Omega_s(x_i)=e^{\frac{\mp s}{\log x_i}}$$

Similarly,

$$\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n s_i \bigg) \Delta h=\pm n x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}h$$

has solution given by a product

$$h:=\prod_{i=1}^n \Omega_{s_i}(x)$$

To conceptually think about this, we can think about $g$ and $h$ as specific projections of a more general product space, $\Phi$.

$$ \Phi:=\prod_{i=1}^n \Omega_{s_i}(x_i) $$

And realize that lattice points aside from $(1,n)$ and $(n,1)$ don't correspond to solutions to either of the PDE's.

Returning to the $(1+1)$ case and the initial system of equations at the very top of this post and taking the Mellin transform of $\Omega$ can I expect to recover a transformed version of the following nonlinear equation?

$$2\sqrt{s}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s} \sqrt{\mp \Omega_s(x)}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\pm\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x)}$$

Well the Mellin transform of $$s \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\Omega_s(x)=\pm x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x)$$

which is only valid for the $-$ sign,

returns

$$r^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial r^3} \chi_s(r)= s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\chi_s(r)$$

with particular solution $$ \chi_s(r)=2\sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{rs}) $$

where $K_1$ is a modified Bessel function.

> How do you take the Mellin transform of the nonlinear equation though?

I'm interested in this because then I could have $\chi_s(r)$ simultaneously satisfying a transformed version of this system:

$$
\begin{cases}
2\sqrt{s}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s} \sqrt{\mp \Omega_s(x)}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\pm\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x)} \\
 s \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\Omega_s(x)=\pm x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x) 
\end{cases}
$$

which would complete this system:

$$
\begin{cases}
???\\
r^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial r^3} \chi_s(r)= s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\chi_s(r)
\end{cases}
$$

for Cauchy data given by
$$\chi_s(r)|_{r=0}$$

Comment: Please provide what you have tried to your post.

Comment: John, first of all the second equation in the system is parabolic *only for a choice of  the sign* of the right hand side (precisely, the sign $+$). Moreover this PDE is linear but it is degenerate, since for $x=0$ or $s=0$ you have respectively that the right side and/or the left side of the equation vanish. This seems to suggest that an approach  based on the Mellin transform respect to the $x$ variable may work, but even so, it is necessary to state out initial and/or boundary values. Well, my two cents.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri do you have any suggestions for boundary conditions I could impose on this system of equations?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the theory PDEs on manifold: nevertheless I think that in your case, you do not need boundary conditions, but instead you need initial value conditions i.e. Cauchy data. Precisely you need $\Omega_s(x)|_{s=0}$, and this means that you know the initial state of your foliation and want to know how it evolves as $s$ varies.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I made some edits. Mainly I ask how to take the Mellin transform of the nonlinear equation in the system. The nonlinearity is tripping me up when trying to employ the transform on the RHS wrt the $x$ variable.